# Handle Outlook send event

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I am trying to create an Outlook add-in using VB.NET

When a user clicks on the send button in a meeting invite, I want to handle the send event, to read fields and do application specific persisting.

I am able to capture a mail send event, but the code is not fired when I modify it for a meeting send event.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple add this function in class **"ThisAddIn"** and before the message send, this function will execute.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.ItemSend
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello from ThisAddIn!")
End Sub
```